# Why does seekp() fail in this case?

Tags: c++, file, file-pointer

I am using this program to modify every vowel in text.txt to become the hashtag ('#')

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::fstream iofile{ "text.txt", std::ios::in | std::ios::out };

    char chChar;

    while (iofile.get(chChar))
    {
        switch (chChar)
        {
        case 'a':
        case 'e':
        case 'i':
        case 'o':
        case 'u':
        case 'A':
        case 'E':
        case 'I':
        case 'O':
        case 'U':

            iofile.seekp(-1, std::ios::cur);

            iofile << '#';

            iofile.seekg(iofile.tellg(), std::ios::beg); 
        }
    }
}
```

So if the initial content of text.txt is

```
something is funny
```

It will turn to

```
s#m#th#ng #s f#nny
```

The problem is this line

```
iofile.seekg(iofile.tellg(), std::ios::beg);
```

This line keeps the file pointer in the same position so I thought I might change the line to this

```
iofile.seekg(0, std::ios::cur);
```

I thought this will do the same thing but it didn't. When I run the program the console just stops there and doesn't stop, and text.txt starts printing weird things. But when I replace it with this line, it works again

```
iofile.seekg(1, std::ios::cur);
```

I thought this should move the file pointer too far (we should remain it in the position but here we move it pass 1 letter). However, this works. What is happening?

Comment: "This line keeps the file pointer in the same position" Why do anything at all, then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a good question! I was able to reproduce your issue using Microsoft Visual Studio Community Edition 2019. However, using Visual Studio Code and g++ 9.3.0, I didn't get the same problem. It seems to be a compiler issue, specifically with Microsoft Visual C++.

The [C++ standard](https://eel.is/c++draft/filebuf#2) refers to the C standard library regarding restrictions on file streams:

> The restrictions on reading and writing a sequence controlled by an
> object of class basic_­filebuf<charT, traits> are the same as for
> reading and writing with the C standard library FILEs.

The C standard library (7.19.5.3 paragraph 6) says:

> When a file is opened with update mode ('+' as the second or third
> character in the above list of mode argument values), both input and
> output may be performed on the associated stream. However, **output
> shall not be directly followed by input without an intervening call to
> the fflush function or to a file positioning function (fseek, fsetpos,
> or rewind), and input shall not be directly followed by output without
> an intervening call to a file positioning function**, unless the input
> operation encounters endof-file.

In other words: you have to perform a flush or seek when switching between input and output for a filestream. Now, this line:

```
iofile.seekg(0, std::ios::cur);
```

should perform a seek (to the same position relative to the current stream position), but with MSVC++ that doesn't seem to be happening, and undefined behaviour subsequently follows. However, when you seek from the beginning of the file by specifying `std::ios::beg` a seek is actually performed and your program works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

```
iofile << '#';
iofile.flush();  // flush buffer when switching from output to input
iofile.seekg(0, std::ios::cur);
```

There is a book I am recently reading about iostreams, "Standard C++ IOStreams and Lcocales". The book describes in section 1.4.3 "Bidirectional File Streams: Switching from output to intput",

> When output has been written to the bidirectional file streams, a read attempt immediately after writing to the file stream will lead to "undefined result."  .... .... The read operation might fail without indicating this failure in anyway;

The author mentioned that the stream must be flushed before reading after writing, and it is also written that the call seekg(0, ios_base::beg) has the effect of emptying the internal buffer, but I'm not sure if seekg() called with different value on second parameter like ios_base::cur also works.